# why is my ID of label not increasing when i add a dynamic list item in JS

Tags: javascript, html

so i am adding a list item to the page when ever the user fillis out the info of a textbox and hits add. It puts it in the format:

```
  <label id="cb1">list item</label>
  <label id="cb1">list item2</label>
```

but it never increases the one to 2.
here's the function i am using.

```
   function addItem(name) {
  var container = $('#sortable');
  var inputs = container.find('input');
  var id = inputs.length+1;

  $('<li /> ', { 'id': 'cb'+id, text:''+ name }).appendTo(container);
 $('').appendTo(container); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.find("li")` since that's what you're inserting:

```js
function addItem(name) {
  var container = $('#sortable');
  var listItems = container.find('li');
  var id = listItems.length + 1;
  console.log(id);

  $('<li /> ', {
    'id': 'cb' + id,
    text: name
  }).appendTo(container);
}
```

```css
li:after {
  content: " (id: " attr(id) ")"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="addItem('some name')" value="click to add">
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="cb1">First Name</li>
</ul>
<div class="sidenote">The id indicator is displayed by CSS</div>
```